# changing owner of record to user in another business unit dynamcis 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, security-roles

I have an issue related to security role. Below the details.

User A belongs to Security group SG1 and User B belongs to Security group SG2:
Both the roles have below privileges(same) on a custom entity, but the Business Unit is different for both Security Group.

create: user level, Read: Business Unit , Write: user level, Append:Business Unit, Append To:Business Unit, Assign:User level , Share:Business Unit

When  user A in SG1 trying to assign his record to a user B in SG2, I am getting Access Denied error.
When the owner changes user A will loose access and get the error. But here, even if I am getting the Access Denied error the owner is not changing in entity, when I am reloading the record the owner is still User A(I think the save is not happening).

Error Log:

> Exception Message: Principal with id ef346db1-c98f-ec11-b400-000d3ac25c59 does not have ReadAccess right(s) for record with id ef346db1-c98f-ec11-b400-000d3ac25c59 of entity my_product. Details: {"CallerPrincipal":{"PrincipalId":"038cfa23-c74e-ec11-8c62-6045bd8f574d","Type":8,"IsUserPrincipal":true},"OwnerPrincipal":{"PrincipalId":"87242295-6ef2-ea11-a815-000d3a23ca40","Type":8,"IsUserPrincipal":true},"ObjectId":"ef348db1-c98f-ec11-b400-000d3ac25c59","ObjectTypeCode":10501,"EntityName":"my_product","ObjectBusinessUnitId":"a4854691-c946-ec11-8c62-000d3a472098","RightsToCheck":"ReadAccess","RoleAccessRights":"None","PoaAccessRights":"None","HsmAccessRights":"None","GrantedAccessRights":"None","Messages":["PrincipalHasOwnerPrincipalWithAtLeastBasicPrivilegeDepth = False","EntityUserGroupRights = None","MinimumPrivilegeDepthRequired = Local","SecLib::AccessCheckEx2 failed. Owner Data: roleCount=1, privilegeCount=822, accessMode=0; Principal Data: roleCount=1, privilegeCount=822, accessMode=0"],"EntityOwnershipTypeMask":1,"CallerInfo":{"IsSystemUser":false,"IsSupportUser":false,"IsAdministrator":false,"IsCustomizer":false,"IsDisabled":false,"IsIntegrationUser":false,"Teams":null,"Roles":null},"ReadOnlyState":"UserAndOrgFullAccess","IsHsmEnabled":false,"HsmInfo":null,"AccessOrigin":null}
>
> ErrorCode: -2147187962
> HexErrorCode: 0x80048306
>
> ErrorDetails:
> 0: my_product
> 1: ef346db1-c98f-ec11-b400-000d3ac25c59
> 2: 10501
> 3: ReadAccess
> 4: ef346db1-c98f-ec11-b400-000d3ac25c59
> 5: 8
> ApiExceptionSourceKey: Step/Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.ImageRetrievalStep
> ApiStepKey: 84b9d1cb-3e30-11db-b951-000cf1fe02ff
> ApiDepthKey: 1
> ApiActivityIdKey: c6338644-38d6-422f-9ccc-2d1284ef241d
> ApiPluginSolutionNameKey: System
> ApiStepSolutionNameKey: System
> ApiExceptionCategory: ClientError
> ApiExceptionMessageName: unManagedIdsAccessDenied
> ApiExceptionHttpStatusCode: 403

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior.

---

Issue 1 - **Assign:User level**

This limits the assign privilege to another BU user, Change it to BU level and it should work.

---

Issue 2 (eventually you will face) - **Read: Business Unit**

As the users (SG) belongs to different BUs and Role has only BU level read, the moment a record is assigned to another cross BU user - the original owner lose access and read privilege for that particular record. Like you mentioned the error will popup.

Comment: My issue is, the pop up is showing that I dont have access to that record. But actually, the owner is not changing. When the page reloads the record is still mine(I need to change the owner). The save is not happening. I have another entity where the user is having same privilege and same functionality. There also I am getting access denied popup, but the owner is changing to new user.

Comment: @Reshma can you check the guid belongs to which record and which team missing privilege, then we can figure out the actual entity in trouble. Check if any plugin triggering on assign or any relationship behavior which is cascading that bubble and throws the issue.

Comment: I have an postupdate plugin, but I tried by disabling the plugin step. also, plugin is running at system user context. When you say 'which team missing privilege' on record, how can I find that? I have the record id.

Comment: @Reshma principalid is team (type 8) in above error text

Comment: caller principalid is my id and owner pricipalid is the new owner's id. As per the above error, I am the caller and other user is the owner of the record. and thats why I am getting access denied error. But actually this record is not getting saved, when the record reloads still I am the owner. If I have read privilege at Organnization level, I am not getting any error. But as per my requirement, I can have only BU level read permission. But I need to change the owner to a different BU user

Comment: Is there anything we can assume from the below details 
ErrorDetails: 
 0: my_product
 1: 115ad74c-e487-ec11-93b0-6045bd8f37d4
 2: 10501
 3: ReadAccess
 4: 038cfa23-c74e-ec11-8c62-6045bd8f574d
 5: 8
 ApiExceptionSourceKey: Step/Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.ImageRetrievalStep
 ApiStepKey: 84b9d1cb-3e30-11db-b951-000cf1fe02ff
 ApiDepthKey: 1
 ApiActivityIdKey: db0ff555-fe85-4ff3-889b-e77da7b24768
 ApiPluginSolutionNameKey: System
 ApiStepSolutionNameKey: System
 ApiExceptionCategory: ClientError
 ApiExceptionMessageName: unManagedIdsAccessDenied
 ApiExceptionHttpStatusCode: 403

Comment: Is there any way we can customize the Access denied alert message to a more user friendly one?